# Copying text from linux to windows notepad

Tags: linux, redhat

I would like to know, how to copy the entire lines of text from vi editor in Redhat to a notepad in windows.

If the size of the text to be copied is minimal, it can be easily done by selecting the lines through mouse and copying to notepad. However I have come across the situation of copying thousands of lines.

Comment: Are Redhat and Windows run on the same machine (e.g., through virtualbox or vmware) ?

Comment: I am using putty to access Redhat...

Comment: Is there any reason to not to use winscp to get the file on windows and then do the copy-paste ?

Answer (score 0):

If i say straight forward answer then there is no way i guess,
but workaround is there,

1. Make a public share of samba (not more than 1 min)
2. Access from windows
3. Create empty file from windows
4. At Linux box run

> cat {path_to_file_you_want_to_copy_content} >> /public/empty_file

for eg:

> cat abc >> /public/empty.txt

Hope that resolves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a file as the media, and use the sz -be coomand send the file to windows.As a suggestion, you can search google about rz/sz command for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If i say straight forward answer then there is no way i guess..,
but try below use cases..,

1. download and install winscp software and connect to your instance (your linux machine) using username and password. Then copy your files from linux to windows.
2. if your linux is a virtual machine (running on putty or vmware) using mouse you can directly copy the conent of file in vi editor in linux machine and paste in new or existed file in windows.